# Order posts by ID in the given order

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, order

In the back-office of my theme, the users can choose which posts to display in the front page, and they can also choose **in which order the selected posts should appear**.

I have tried like this:

```
$aPostsIDs = array(1,3,2); // Note the 3 should appear before the 2
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 
                  'post__in' => $aPostsIDs,
                  'order_by' => 'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$aPostsIDs).')'));
```

But as expected it doesn't work. The right way to do it [according to the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) is:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $aPostsIDs;
    $orderby_statement = 'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$aPostsIDs).')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

But that still doesn't work! The posts are ordered by ID (1, 2, 3) instead of the given order (1, 3, 2).

Where should I look?
Thanks

Comment: Ok I have found why my second example wasn't working, it was because the add_filter() call needed to be declared **before** the call to query_posts()!

This is now working as expected:

    $aSectionsIDs = array(1,3,2);
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
    function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
     global $aSectionsIDs;
     $orderby_statement = 'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$aSectionsIDs).')';
     return $orderby_statement;
    }
    query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 
          'post__in' => $aSectionsIDs));

If I place the query_posts() call just before a

Comment: This system is really stupid! First I need to wait 8 hours to answer my own question (what if I have figured it out before that delay??), and second it suggests me as an alternative to post my answer as a comment, but the comment is limited in length so I cannot explain the answer in details. And it removed all line breaks, code and text formating... -_- Anyway I didn't have enough chars left to finish my sentence in my previous comment, so here it is: If I place the query_posts() call just before add_filter() call then it just stops working.

Answer (score 5):

Starting in WordPress 3.5, the `orderby` parameter will allow the value `post__in` to sort by the order of the `post__in` parameter, just like in your example.

It may not be ideal to wait or require 3.5+, but this will almost certainly be the best and easiest way to do what you're looking to do.

Here's the [relevant trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13729) if you want the details.

Comment: so useful, thank you!