# Can't order the query result as given posts id's array

Tags: wp-query, filters

I want to order a query result by the same order as the post id's array given. E.g. I have:

```
$arrayPostsIds = array(30,5,17,10);
```

and I want to get the posts in that order. So after trying [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72627/order-posts-by-id-in-the-given-order):

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_join_paged($join_paged_statement) {
    global $arrayPostsIds_id;
    $join_paged_statement = 'FIELD(ID,'.implode(',',$arrayPostsIds).')';
    return $join_paged_statement;   
}
```

and then I get the new result, which should match the above order:

```
$temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use  
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $arrayPostsIds, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 'date_query' => $date_query ) );
```

but I'm getting the result **ordered by ID**, so it's not keeping the desired order. Am I forgetting anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your filter and [add `orderby'=>'post__in'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). That sort order in not automatic when you supply IDs.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 
  array(
     'post__in' => $arrayPostsIds,
     'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
     'date_query' => $date_query ,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
  ) 
);
```

Comment: I had also tried this, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: If `$arrayPostsIds` is set correctly this should work. You will need to remove your filter.

Comment: Oh man! It works just removing the filter! Thank you for your fast answer.